# How to recover master from a backup on moosefs-ce.2.0

Tags: moosefs

My mfs version is moosefs-ce-2.0, it is installed on debian6 which is ext3 filesystem. There are a master and a metalogger and some chunkserver, when my master is down. How to recover master from metalogger? The documentation moosefs.org provided is outdated, I can't find more detailed information on documentaton. Or how to config muti-master on moosefs-ce-2.0?

Answer (score 4):

It *is* described in the documentation. You can find the documentation here: [MooseFS Documentation](http://moosefs.com/support). Paragraph 4.2 (page 19) of MooseFS User's Manual "Master metadata restore from metaloggers" says:

> 4.2 Master metadata restore from metaloggers
>
> In MooseFS Community Edition basic configuration there can be only one master and several metaloggers. If for some reason you loose all metadata files and changelogs from master server you can use data from metalogger to restore your data. To start dealing with recovery first you need to transfer all data stored on metalogger in `/var/lib/mfs` to master metadata folder. Files on metalogger will have ml prefix prepended to the filenames. After all files are copied, you need to create `metadata.mfs` file from changelogs and `metadata.mfs.back` files. To do this we need to use the command `mfsmaster -a`. Mfsmaster starts to build new metadata file and starts mfsmaster process.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't very well received on Stack Overflow. As it stands your answer relies on external information which may or may not be available in future, please edit the relevant information from the linked source into your answer. Additionally your second paragraph and final salutation could be seen as self-promotional and spammy, which may well cause your answer to be deleted with a vengeance, I'd advise removing them.